# folder dialog in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, openfiledialog

is there a folder dialog control in asp.net?
i want the user to press a button and select a folder (not a file). i tried using the input in this way:

```
 <input type="file" runat="server" id="d" />
```

but it enabled me to browse a file and not a folder.
any help?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: i want the user to choose his own folder in which files will be automatically saved in. thats it...

Comment: Where are the files coming from?

Comment: the folders are located on the server and the files are located at the client side. so a client chooses a folder on the server and upload his files there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to build something like this; use the AJAX control toolkit modal popup extender to display the window to the user, then build the UI yourself.  to show the root and subfolders.  Maybe a treeview to represent this.  It's doable, as long as you are talking folders on the web server.

If you are talking folder on the client's machine, you would need active X or silverlight.  So it depends on what you are looking for.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this in HTML - you would have to write something custom (perhaps using ActiveX or Silverlight) that would allow you to do this.